# Waiting on method finish before executing next line

Tags: javascript

```
@track var

function1() {
   function2();
   console.log(var); 
}
function2() {
   var = 2;
}
```

For function 2 i am querying a controller to get related data, but when I test the output, the results are blank as the console.log hasn't got the var variable yet. How do i wait for function2 to finish before proceeding with the next lines of code so the variables aren't empty?

Comment: Yes thank you, but how can it await on a function finish other than a timer?

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer on that post. you have to use the `await` keyword on the apex method you are querying the record from. in your case, should be something like: `this.records = await YourApexMethodHere();` (also try not to use reserved words as your variable names, ie: `var`)
here you can find another [sample code](https://www.avirai.com/post/using-async-await-to-call-apex-method-imperatively)